# Optimize applying a conditional filter to pandas dataframe for large input list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large (>3 million rows) pandas dataframe that I'd like to apply a single condition (a simple greater than less than) to a large number of inputs. I'd skip the "new_df" step below, but putting it here for clarity.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"X":[0,2,3,6,13],
                   "Y":[10,12,16,8,22]})
input  = 13    
new_df = df[(input >= df["X"]) & (input <= df["Y"])]
inds   = new_df.index

print(df)
print(new_df)
print(inds)

    X   Y
0   0  10
1   2  12
2   3  16
3   6   8
4  13  22

    X   Y
2   3  16
4  13  22

Int64Index([2, 4], dtype='int64')
```

---

The Y value will always be > X and X will always be sorted. This is simple , but instead of "input=13" I'd like to apply this filter to thousands of input values and get indices back for each input.

Something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"X":[0,2,3,6,13],
                   "Y":[10,12,16,8,22]})
ind_list = []
for input in range(1,5000):
    inds = df[(input >= df["X"]) & (input <= df["Y"])].index
    ind_list.append(inds)
```

It works fine, but repeatedly calling a conditional filter on a 3+ million row dataframe over and over takes some time. I feel like there's probably a more efficient way. Any suggestions?

And to be clear since my previous question was flagged as a duplicate for some reason, I am not asking **how** to get the indices of a dataframe, I'm looking for alternative more efficient ways than conditional filtering inside of a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can parallelize all available cores of your CPU. I use the convenient and simple [parallelbar](https://pypi.org/project/parallelbar/) library. The idea is simple. Create a function that returns a list of indexes. Run this function on a thread pool and pass a list of inputs to the pool.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from parallelbar import progress_map  #pip install parallelbar
#create dataframe with 3000 000 rows
df = pd.DataFrame({"X":np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=3000_000),
                   "Y":np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=3000_000)})
# synchronous cicle
ind_list = []
for input in range(1,5000):
    inds = df[(input >= df["X"]) & (input <= df["Y"])].index
    ind_list.append(inds)
```

```
Outpu: Wall time: 25 s
```

```py
#create simple function
def foo(inp):
    return df[(inp >= df["X"]) & (inp <= df["Y"])].index

#run in the thread pool with map method
%%time
result = progress_map(foo, range(1,5000), executor='threads')
```

```
Output: Wall time is 17 s.
```

It's a little faster.
also, you can pass to numpy array. Operations directly on these arrays are always faster than pandas.

```py
np_val = df.values

#synchronous cycle with numpy
%%time
ind_list = []
for i in range(1,5000):
    inds = np.where((i >= np_val[:,0]) & (i <= np_val[:,1]))[0]
    ind_list.append(inds)
```

```
Output: Wall time is 15 s
```

```py
def foo(inp):
    return np.where((inp >= np_val[:,0]) & (inp <= np_val[:,1]))[0]

%%time
result = progress_map(foo, range(1,5000), executor='threads')
```

```
Outpu:   Wall time is 8.5 s
```

Total speedup: `25/8.5 ~ 3`